# How do I move my dogecoins from my DOGE wallet into my VERGE wallet?

Tags: dogecoin, wallet-import

I have been reading online about people who just backed up their DOGE wallet and then copied the `wallet.dat` file into their VERGE wallet installation and voilà! When the VERGE wallet was opened the coins showed up. But I can't figure out where this wallet.dat file needs to be copied to for the VERGE wallet installation? If anyone knows how I should be going about this I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Your verge wallet will have made itself a wallet.dat file in its default data directory if you did not specificy a different directory yourself. You can overwrite that wallet.dat file with your one from dogecoindark if you haven't used the new one at all (obviously if you have, you should back it up). I have never used verge wallet before, but if it uses the same default location as bitcoin, you should be able to find the data directory in `%APPDATA%\Verge` on windows, `~/.verge/` on linux, or `~/Library/Application Support/Verge/` on Mac OSX.